# ajax content not be loaded, what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load some data from a json file, but the content doesn't show up and also the browser console doesn't return any error. Here's the script:

```
(function($){
  $(window).load(function(){
    $.getJSON('./assets/js/data.json', function(datas){
        console.log(datas);
    }); //get JSON
  }); //window.load
});
```

And am calling the script file like:

```
    <script src="assets/js/ajax.js"></script>
```

What could be wrong?

--------------more info about issue

when i use $(function(){}) AND $(window).load() chrome dont return any error in console, but the data.json not issued in network tab.
and when i don't use $(function(){}) AND $(window).load() the data.json is issued but cant load and the chrome return below errors:
[image: chrome returned error in console]

Comment: just a side note, you dont need `$(function(){})` AND `$(window).load()`.

Comment: I take it you _are_ loading jQuery befre you do this?

Comment: can you see under your network tab that the request is issued?

Comment: I think `'./assets/js/data.json'` should be just `data.json`, seeing that both lie script and json file in the same directory

Comment: @hungerpain i did it befre but in chrome this error returned:
http://imageupload.co.uk/files/163ck76xrvitgtuhd8tw.png

Comment: @MikeW yes that's right

Comment: @intuitivepixel yes that issued but in it's time latency wrote Pending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh god KILL me, all of this issue happened for only a brain crash. i just missed to remove a "," in the data.json.

thanks to all for answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you assets folder is in root then change you code to(remove leading dot(.)) change './assets/js/data.json' path to '/assets/js/data.json'

```
    (function($){
      $(window).load(function(){
          $.getJSON('/assets/js/data.json', function(datas){
          console.log(datas);
        }); //get JSON
      }); //window.load
    });
```

Comment: That doesn't necessarily have to work since hi didn't use a leading '/' in his `<script></script>` block.

Comment: @putvande leading '/' will send request to folder from root so in any case if this code is executed from a page which is in nested sub directory will not break 'assets/js/data.json' will also work but for page which are on root

Comment: @RajeshKumar i did it but results is same

Comment: @Bobak what response is returned in browser console after $.get request?

Answer (score 0):

Remove function($) then try it like below:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $.getJSON('./assets/js/data.json', function(datas){
        console.log(datas);
    }); //get JSON
  });
```